# Installing expo-notifications results in error "Cannot read property '__expo_module_name__' of undefined"

Tags: expo

I'm trying to install [expo-notifications](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#usage). For development, I rely on Expo Go.

After I `yarn add` that library and add a simple `import * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications';` in my App.js, I get this error:

```
 ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property '__expo_module_name__' of undefined, js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes
```

Just removing that import statement solves the problem entirely, so the bug is clearly related to the expo-notifications library.

I know that the "Invariant violation" part is likely a red herring and that it's the first line of the error that's the real problem.

I'm working with these versions of libraries:

```
    "expo": "~48.0.15",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.18.1",
    "react-native": "0.71.11",
```

Doing some digging, the variable `__expo_module_name__` shows up in expo-modules-core, in [EventEmitter.ts](https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/33bd1a4587c1df8b2834e831c6cf4454c2d24730/packages/expo-modules-core/src/EventEmitter.ts#L7). Perhaps something in my setup of this library is broken? I've already tried removing node-modules/ and yarn.lock and reinstalling everything with `yarn`.

Any suggestions on what to try?

Comment: Tracing the code some more, EventEmitter is getting invoked here: https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/33bd1a4587c1df8b2834e831c6cf4454c2d24730/packages/expo-notifications/src/TokenEmitter.ts#LL14C39-L14C55. But neither EventEmitter nor TokenEmitter have been touched in a couple of years. I suspect this might be something wrong with how I installed the library, perhaps something to do with linking? Any advice on how to troubleshoot?

Comment: Any luck? Having the same issue